# $y^5 =(x+2)^4+(e^x)(ln y)−15$ finding $\frac{dy}{dx}$ at $(0,1)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

[image]

Unsure what to do regarding the $y^5$. 
Should I convert it to a $y$= function and take the $5$ root of the other side. Then differentiate? Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: That could work, or you could use the chain rule on $y$.

Comment: I revised your question tags; note the addition of the implicit differentiation tag is a hint as to how to solve the question.

Comment: I'm just unsure what would happen to e^x ln y. getting a bit confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately we cannot rearrange this to find $y$. Fortunately we can still use *implicit differentiation* to find a derivative. Take the derivative of all terms w.r.t. $x$, using the chain rule and treating $y$ as a function of $x$ - we obtain

$$
5y^4\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = 4(x+2)^3 + \mathrm{e}^x\ln y +\frac{\mathrm{e}^x}{y}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}.
$$

Note that we used the product rule for the $\mathrm{e}^x\ln y$ term. Now the trick is to rearrange to solve for the derivative, and then substitute $(x,y) = (0,1)$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: That is very help full. thanks a lot mate, should have it from here.

Comment: It can be more pleasant to substitute in the displayed formula and then solve.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, perhaps, but then you wouldn't have a formula for the derivative for all $x,y$.

Comment: i had dy/dx=1.2 is this correct??

Comment: If I do as andre said I get $5y' = 32 + y'$, so $4y' = 32$, $y' = 8$.

Comment: Bennet, can you show further how you would rearrange from where you have left the equation? just trying to follow :)